# I need to insert null values for missing index in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a dataset

```
x  text
1  one
2  two
4  four
5  five
7  seven
```

now I want output as

```
x  text
1  one
2  two
3  null
4  four
5  five
6  null
7  seven
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
#if x is column
#df = df.set_index('x').reindex(np.arange(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + 1))
#if x is index
df = df.reindex(np.arange(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + 1))
print (df)
    text
x       
1    one
2    two
3    NaN
4   four
5   five
6    NaN
7  seven
```

Comment: i have tried but i am getting this error
->AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: @RahulVarma - use second answer - `df = df.reindex(np.arange(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + 1))`

Comment: @RahulVarma - what is `print(df.index)` ?